# When i change the Display property of the "select", "button" and "input" elements to "inline", they still behaves like "line-block". Why?

Tags: html

Those elements are supposed to be inline-block by default, but when i change their display property to "inline", they keep behaving like inline-block. Their width and height is still respected. I don't understand why? Same thing doesn't happen with a Div element.

```
<select name="random">
    <option>some text</option>
    <option>another text</option>
    <option>more text</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select {
    display:inline;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    }
```

And here's an example with Div to demonstrate that changing the display property to inline makes the element behave like an inline.

```
<div>some text</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inspect the element and take a look at the `Computed` tab. You will see that your browser is overriding your declaration and still treating the `select` box as `inline-block`.

[image]

```css
select {
  display:inline;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<select name="random">
    <option>some text</option>
    <option>another text</option>
    <option>more text</option>
</select>
```

If you want to use `display:inline`, you should add a wrapper and set it there instead:

```css
.select-wrapper {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select name="random">
    <option>some text</option>
    <option>another text</option>
    <option>more text</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why the browser overrides the CSS?